# How to assign a random value in a select statement in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select a random value of table for each row of a another table.

I have the following code:

```
SELECT T1.COL1,(SELECT TOP 1 t2.COL2 FROM T2 ORDER BY NEWID())FROM T1
```

I understand the reason why it does not work. It selects a random value from T2, but it is the same for each row selected from T1.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a tricky part of SQL Server.  It is a bit too aggressive in optimizing queries.  You can prevent this with a correlation clause:

```
SELECT T1.COL1,
       (SELECT TOP 1 t2.COL2 FROM T2 where t1.col1 is not null ORDER BY NEWID() )
FROM T1
```

The added clause `where t1.col1 is not null` will force SQL Server to compute the subquery for each row.  Without this, as in your original query, the subquery is being computed once, and then getting cached.

Comment: Great! My answer was of much greater length: http://rextester.com/RZKN19659  (I feel that my sqlserver skills are covered with rust)

Comment: @Ingaz, Gordon's query runs the subquery for each row of `T1`. It may be quite slow. It would be much better to enumerate rows from T2 and join two tables together on a random row number. Thus the tables would be scanned only once. I'll test on my system and write an answer.

Comment: Yes. My variant must be more efficient but: it breaks when first table is bigger than second. Gordon variant never breaks.

Comment: @Ingaz, efficiency depends on the size of the tables. In my test the difference was 1200 times. See my answer.

Comment: If someone cares about efficiency on larger tables, they should ask *another* question, with more detailed information.

Answer (score 3):

The query suggested by Gordon is correct and it produces expected result, but it is quite inefficient if your tables have more than a handful of rows.

I'll repeat it here:

```
SELECT T1.COL1,
       (SELECT TOP 1 t2.COL2 FROM T2 where t1.col1 is not null ORDER BY NEWID() )
FROM T1
```

Essentially, it runs the subquery for each row of the `T1` table. The subquery reads the whole `T2` table, sorts the whole table, picks one row and discards the rest. The `T2` table is scanned as many times as there are rows in `T1`.

The query can return the same value `t2.COL2` for different rows of `T1`.

If this is the requirement and part of the definition of "random selection", then you can't do much about it.

But, if there is no such a requirement and it is allowed to map two tables row-to-row without repetitions, then there is much faster way to do it by scanning the source tables only once.

In my test SQL Server 2008 I have a table `Numbers` with 100,000 rows with numbers from 1 to 100,000 and a table `Calendar` with dates from 2000-01-01 to 2037-12-31 (13880 rows).

So, I wrote two queries:

**Row number**

```
WITH
CTE1
AS
(
    SELECT
        T1.dt
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dt) AS rn1
    FROM dbo.Calendar AS T1
)
,CTE2
AS
(
    SELECT
        T2.Number
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) AS rn2
    FROM dbo.Numbers AS T2
)
SELECT
    CTE1.dt
    ,CTE2.Number
FROM
    CTE1
    INNER JOIN CTE2 ON CTE1.rn1 = CTE2.rn2
;
```

**Subquery**

```
SELECT T1.dt,
    (SELECT TOP 1 t2.Number FROM dbo.Numbers AS T2 where t1.dt is not null ORDER BY NEWID() )
FROM dbo.Calendar AS T1
;
```

I ran them in SQL Sentry Plan Explorer and compared their execution plans and performance:

[image: stats]

As you can see from this screenshot, the RowNumber query finished in 233 ms and Subquery variant took 289,950 ms. About 1200 times more.

It becomes apparent what is going on when you look at the execution plans:

**RowNumber**

[image: rownumber]

You can see that both tables are scanned once and merge joined together.

**SubQuery**

[image: subquery]

Here the `Numbers` table is scanned and sorted 13880 times.

---

I kept the RowNumber variant simple to illustrate the concept. It will not work as intended if `T1` has more rows than `T2`.

It is easy to fix it, though by cross joining `T2` to itself as many times as needed to generate enough rows before calculating row numbers.

Comment: Vladimir, it's great but OP never asked "How to do it efficiently". So I prefer his variant to mine or yours.

Comment: @Ingaz, no problem. I just could not go past it and hence posted a second answer. It is totally up to the people reading this in the future to decide which variant they prefer.